# ImportError: No module named comtypes

Tags: wxpython, py2exe, comtypes

I was wondering why whenever I try to make a FlashWin program with python, it gives me this error after compiling it using py2exe, and opening it:

```
File "wx\lib\flashwin.pyc", line 15, in <module>
File "wx\lib\activex.pyc", line 36, in <module>
File "wx\lib\comtypes\__init__.pyc", line 24, in <module>
ImportError: No module named comtypes
```

For the record, when I installed wxPython, it didn't have the comtypes folder, so I manually downloaded it and placed it in the wx\lib folder.
So what do you think the problem is? It only happens when I code FlashWin/ActiveX programs.

P.S: I'm still a beginner in Python/wxPython, so please excuse any mistakes I make.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible issues:

1. You need to install comtypes rather than just copying to the folder,
   this is usually by download, unpack into a local directorys then in
   that directory type: `python setup.py install`
2. You may have to add comtypes to the projects list of required
   packages for py2exe to pick it up correctly.  This is usually done by added them to the packages list in the project setup.py file.  Some packages have additional requirements.

See also [Working with specific pakages](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules).

Comment: How can I add the comtypes in the project list of required packages?

Comment: See link I have added to the answer above.